# Image srcset for 2x and min-width combined?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to have a responsive image that has a mobile image (determined by max-width: 800px), then after that width jumps to a @1x desktop image or a desktop image for retina screens (desktop @2x), if they have a dpi of 2x.

Is it possible to achieve this in the same srcset in a more or less compatible way with modern browsers?

Comment: Hie thee to the Supreme Sorcerer Google, who must surely have a remedy for thine dilemma. Seriously though, what have you tried?

Comment: [This should point you in the right direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/picture)

Comment: @Mers picture is amazing and solves this but IE11 compatibility is null :\

Comment: @AlfaTeK, yup it sure is - unfortunately, good ol' IE does not support the `<picture>` element.  You can try exploring [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to see if you can achieve the effect you are after on IE.